# XSLT – Pass attributes to create parent elements, then order filtered results

Tags: xslt

I'm getting back to learning XSLT after a while and find myself struggling with the push approach.

From the following (simplified) document:

```
<Index>
    <Person id="Je1" age="30" nationality="Fra">Jean</Person>
    <Person id="Ma1" age="30" nationality="Eng">Mary</Person>
    <Person id="Je2" age="40" nationality="Fra">Jean</Person>
    <Person id="Lu1" age="20" nationality="Ita">Luigi</Person>
    <Person id="He1" age="50" nationality="Gre">Hector</Person>
    <Person id="Pe1" age="45" nationality="Gre">Penelope</Person>
</Index>
```

I would like: 
1. to use the distinct values of the attribute "nationality" to create sorted  elements,
2. to pass the  items to the corresponding  elements
3. to order them according to another original attribute, e.g. "age"

```
<OrderedIndex>
    <Country key="Eng">
        <Person id="Ma1" age="30" nationality="E">Mary</Person>
    </Country>
    <Country key="Fra">
        <Person id="Je1" age="30" nationality="F">Jean</Person>
        <Person id="Je2" age="40" nationality="F">Jean</Person>
    </Country>
    <Country key="Gre">
        <Person id="Pe1" age="45" nationality="Gre">Penelope</Person>
        <Person id="He1" age="50" nationality="Gre">Hector</Person>
    </Country>
    <Country key="Ita">
        <Person id="Lu1" age="20" nationality="Ita">Luigi</Person>
    </Country>
</OrderedIndex>
```

I am managing the first step thus:

```
<xsl:variable name="cou" select="distinct-values(//@nationality)"/>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <List>
    <xsl:for-each select="$cou">
        <xsl:sort/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:element name="country">
            <xsl:attribute name="country">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </List>
</xsl:template>
```

— but am not managing to use `<apply-templates>` or `<for-each>` after that. There is obviously something I don't understand in the selection process.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `distinct-values` is selecting `@n` attributes, but I think you mean to select `@nationality` attributes

```
<xsl:variable name="cou" select="distinct-values(//@nationality)"/>
```

However, `distinct-values` may not be the best choice to use here, because it returns a sequence of atomic values, so you will no longer be in the context of the original XML document. `xsl:for-each-group` may be a better match here

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <OrderedIndex>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Person" group-by="@nationality">
                <xsl:sort select="@nationality"/>
                <Country key="{current-grouping-key()}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:sort select="@age" />
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </Country>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </OrderedIndex>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notes:

- There is really no need to try and output line breaks when outputting XML (unless you do have some special requirement). Just use the `indent` option on `xsl:output`
- The identity template is used to copy the `Person` elements
- Note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) when creating the `key` attribute on the `country` element.

Also note, if you did want to use `distinct-values` you could do it like this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="cou" select="distinct-values(//@nationality)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="root" select="/"/>

    <xsl:key name="people" match="Person" use="@nationality" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <List>
        <xsl:for-each select="$cou">
            <xsl:sort select="." />
            <country key="{.}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="apply-templates select="">
                    <xsl:sort select="@age" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </country>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </List>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice grouping but you forgot '3. to order them according to another original attribute, e.g. "age"' :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly. I corrected the @n it my original question. — I use line breaks to avoid Oxygen returning new lines in front of each attribute – I guess there is an option somewhere to avoid it, but the preference panel is somewhat foreboding to me.