# XSLT – Count the position of each element depending on attribute value

Tags: xslt

From something like:

```
<Play>
    <Character key="Horatio">[...]</Character>
    <Character key="Hamlet">[...]</Character>
    <Character key="Ghost">[...]</Character>
    <Character key="Hamlet">[...]</Character>
    <Character key="Polonius">[...]</Character>
    <Character key="Hamlet">[...]</Character>
    <Character key="Hamlet">[...]</Character>
    <Character key="Queen">[...]</Character>
    <Character key="Horatio">[...]</Character>
</Play>
```

I would like to output a copy that would pass as additional attribute the position of each element among those sharing the same @key, such as:

```
<Play>
    <Character key="Horatio" token="1">[...]</Character>
    <Character key="Hamlet" token="1">[...]</Character>
    <Character key="Ghost" token="1">[...]</Character>
    <Character key="Hamlet" token="2">[...]</Character>
    <Character key="Polonius" token="1">[...]</Character>
    <Character key="Hamlet" token="3">[...]</Character>
    <Character key="Hamlet" token="4">[...]</Character>
    <Character key="Queen" token="1">[...]</Character>
    <Character key="Horatio" token="2">[...]</Character>
</Play>
```

Since this is a kind of follow-up to an earlier ordering question  ([XSLT – Pass attributes to create parent elements, then order filtered results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383933/)), I've tried to use Tim C's answer as my basis and use xsl:number in conjunction with it, but I haven't succeeded.

Many thanks!

Comment: *I've tried to use Tim C's answer* ... please post such an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution would be to group the characters by key and use their position within each group.

If you need to preserve the original order (or create a different order by some other property), try a different approach:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="grp" match="Character" use="@key" />

<xsl:template match="Character">
    <Character key="{@key}" token="{index-of(key('grp', @key)/generate-id(), generate-id())}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Character>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```